# HashSet vs LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

What is the difference between them? I know that

> A LinkedHashSet is an ordered version of HashSet that
>   maintains a doubly-linked List across all elements. Use this class instead of HashSet
>   when you care about the iteration order. When you iterate through a HashSet the
>   order is unpredictable, while a LinkedHashSet lets you iterate through the elements
>   in the order in which they were inserted.

But in sourcecode of LinkedHashSet there are only calling constructors of HashSet. So where is double-linked List and insertion order?

Comment: use Intellij(Ctrl + B) option to track down the answer. :)

Comment: of course you need source code attached. :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The difference between the two are, as you've stated:

> A `LinkedHashSet` is an ordered version of `HashSet` that maintains a doubly-linked List across all elements. Use this class instead of `HashSet` when you care about the iteration order. When you iterate through a `HashSet` the order is unpredictable, while a `LinkedHashSet` lets you iterate through the elements in the order in which they were inserted.

As for your question:

> But in sourcecode of LinkedHashSet there are only calling constructors of HashSet.

The answer lies in **which constructors** the `LinkedHashSet` uses to construct the base class:

```
public LinkedHashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    super(initialCapacity, loadFactor, true);      // <-- boolean dummy argument
}

...

public LinkedHashSet(int initialCapacity) {
    super(initialCapacity, .75f, true);            // <-- boolean dummy argument
}

...

public LinkedHashSet() {
    super(16, .75f, true);                         // <-- boolean dummy argument
}

...

public LinkedHashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    super(Math.max(2*c.size(), 11), .75f, true);   // <-- boolean dummy argument
    addAll(c);
}
```

And (one example of) a `HashSet` constructor that takes a boolean argument is described, and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new, empty linked hash set.  (This package private
 * constructor is only used by LinkedHashSet.) The backing
 * HashMap instance is a LinkedHashMap with the specified initial
 * capacity and the specified load factor.
 *
 * @param      initialCapacity   the initial capacity of the hash map
 * @param      loadFactor        the load factor of the hash map
 * @param      dummy             ignored (distinguishes this
 *             constructor from other int, float constructor.)
 * @throws     IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is less
 *             than zero, or if the load factor is nonpositive
 */
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
    map = new LinkedHashMap<E,Object>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}
```

Comment: A parent class having functionality explicitly for a child class, an ignored argument to distinguish

Comment: Not exactly a clean design using a dummy parameter for constructor disambiguation.

Comment: It is reasonably clean design, because the API is clean (this HashSet constructor is package private). The implementation details do not matter for the users of the class. Maintaining this code could be harder, but in the case of java.util classes, even very small performance improvements can justify that.

Answer (score 38):

**HashSet** is *unordered* and *unsorted* Set.
**LinkedHashSet** is the *ordered version* of HashSet.

The only difference between **HashSet** and **LinkedHashSet** is that:
**LinkedHashSet** maintains the insertion order.

When we iterate through a **HashSet**, the order is unpredictable while it is predictable in case of **LinkedHashSet**.

The reason for how **LinkedHashSet** maintains insertion order is that:
The underlying used data structure is **Doubly-Linked-List**.

Answer (score 26):

`LinkedHashSet`'s constructors invoke the following base class constructor:

```
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
  map = new LinkedHashMap<E, Object>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}
```

As you can see, the internal map is a `LinkedHashMap`. If you look inside `LinkedHashMap`, you'll discover the following field:

```
private transient Entry<K, V> header;
```

This is the linked list in question.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you to use **`LinkedHashSet`** most of the time, because it has **better performance overall**):

1. **Predictable** **iteration** order [LinkedHashSet (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)
2. LinkedHashSet is more expensive for insertions than HashSet;
3. In general slightly better performance than **`HashMap`**, because the most of the time we use Set structures for iterating.

> **Performance tests:**

```
------------- TreeSet -------------
 size       add  contains   iterate
   10       746       173        89
  100       501       264        68
 1000       714       410        69
10000      1975       552        69
------------- HashSet -------------
 size       add  contains   iterate
   10       308        91        94
  100       178        75        73
 1000       216       110        72
10000       711       215       100
---------- LinkedHashSet ----------
 size       add  contains   iterate
   10       350        65        83
  100       270        74        55
 1000       303       111        54
10000      1615       256        58
```

You can see source test page here: [The Final Performance Testing Example](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=122295)

Comment: I don't see any warming up of the JVM before those "benchmarks", so I wouldn't take any of that data seriously. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

You should look at the source of the `HashSet` constructor it calls... it's a special constructor that makes the backing `Map` a `LinkedHashMap` instead of just a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks, in HashSet there is constructor for creating LinkedHashMap, which is called in LinkedHashSet and all logic is in LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 4):

`HashSet` **don't maintain** the order of insertion item
`LinkedHashSet` **maintain** the order of insertion item

Example

```
Set<String> set = ...;// using new HashSet<>() OR new LinkedHashSet<>()
set.add("2");
set.add("1");
set.add("ab");
for(String value : set){
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

`HashSet` output

```
1
ab
2
```

`LinkedHashSet` output

```
2
1
ab
```

Answer (score 3):

HashSet:
Unordered actually.
if u passing the parameter means

```
Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<set.length;i++)
{
  SOP(set)`enter code here`
}
```

Out Put:
May be `2,1,3` not predictable. next time another order.

`LinkedHashSet()` which produce FIFO Order.

Answer (score 3):

**HashSet:**

The underlined data structure is Hashtable.
Duplicate objects are not allowed.insertion order is not preserved and it is based on hash code of objects.
Null insertion is possible(only once).
It implements Serializable, Clonable but not RandomAccess interface.
HashSet is best choose if frequent operation is search operation.

> In HashSet duplicates are not allowed.if users are trying to insert duplicates when we won't get any compile or runtime exceptions. add method returns simply false.

**Constructors:**

> HashSet h=new HashSet(); creates an empty HashSet object with default initial capacity 16 and default fill ratio(Load factor) is 0.75 .
>
> HashSet h=new HashSet(int initialCapacity); creates an empty HashSet object with specified initialCapacity and default fill ration is 0.75.
>
> HashSet h=new HashSet(int initialCapacity, float fillRatio);
>
> HashSet h=new HashSet(Collection c); creates an equivalent HashSet object for the given collection. This constructor meant for inter conversion between collection object.

**LinkedHashSet:**

It is a child class of HashSet. it is exactly same as HashSet including(Constructors and Methods) except the following differences.

Differences
HashSet:

1. The underlined data structure is Hashtable.
2. Insertion order is not preserved.
3. introduced 1.2 version.

LinkedHashSet:

1. The underlined data structure is a combination of LinkedList and Hashtable.
2. Insertion order is preserved.
3. Indroduced in 1.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the constructors called from the `LinkedHashSet` class you will see that internally it's a `LinkedHashMap` that is used for backing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

All Methods and constructors are same but only one difference is LinkedHashset will maintain insertion order but it will not allow duplicates.

Hashset will not maintain any insertion order.
It is combination of List and Set simple :)