# Can LinkedHashSet in this code be replaced with a HashSet?

Tags: java, data-structures

What does the following code do? Can the `LinkedHashSet` be replaced with a `HashSet`?

```
public class CollectionFunction {
    public <E> List<E> function(List<E> list) {
        return new ArrayList<E>(new LinkedHashSet<E>(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashSet vs LinkedHashSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080612/hashset-vs-linkedhashset)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Sam, welcome to SO. If you found any of the answers as what you were looking for, you can select them as accepted to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does the following code do?

It seems like it is used to remove duplicates from a list without changing the order

1. removes duplicates (LinkedHashSet is a Set)
2. maintains insertion order ([LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) has  predictable iteration order)
3. convert back to a List

> Can the LinkedHashSet be replaced with a HashSet?

No, it will not keep the order guaranteed (#2)

Answer (score 1):

A Set is an unordered collection of items, where a list must retain the order of the included items. You cannot use a set like `HashSet` to implement a list, because the order of the items isn't stored. A linked hash set stores these information.

Answer (score 1):

This function is removing the duplicate elements and keeping the insertion order.

if you give `a,b,c,d,a` as input you will get `a,b,c,d` as output.

Yes you can

> replace LinkedHashSet with HashSet if you do not want the insertion
>   order.

Output may be like this `b,c,d,a` if replace LinkedhashSet with HashSet

Answer (score -3):

It creates an ArrayList out of an object implementing the List interface. The ArrayList class has an constructer which takes a Collection:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
You have to lookup if also the HashSet implements Collection
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html.
You also have to lookup if the HashSet provides the according constructer. As the HashSet fulfills both requirements you can replace it :-).